How to export libgdx game as an iOS framework?
I want to embed a libgdx game into the existing iOS app. maybe by exporting the game as an iOS framework and importing it to the app.
I prefer to do that using roboVM but if anyone can guide me to do that using MOE (Multi-OS engine) also be great.
